# Stars magnitude

Tags: magnitude

I have a question: assume two identical stars, but one is 10 times farther than the other from the earth. If the nearest star has a relative magnitude of 5, what is the relative magnitude of the other?

Comment: Why can't you do this simple problem using the definition of the magnitude system and that received flux is proportional to the reciprocal of the square of the distance?

Comment: This is a good question, but it's also one that's very easily answered by looking at any primary or secondary source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @RobJeffries [mentions](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/25092/stars-magnitude#comment42948_25092), you can calculate the difference from the equations which define magnitude and flux. But this particular case is even covered in the [Wikipedia article on apparent magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude#Standard_reference_values):

> For objects within the Milky Way with a given absolute magnitude, 5 is added to the apparent magnitude for every tenfold increase in the distance to the object.

So if the nearest star has magnitude 5, the farthest one has magnitude 5 + 5 = 10.